# Force Class Loading and Unloading (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am loading a class from a string like this

```
Kernel.const_get(some_class_name).new
```

which works, but what is the correct way to do this?

More importantly, is there any way to **unload** a class? I have tried

```
Object.send(:remove_const, some_class_name)
```

but that is not the same as before the class was ever loaded.

Note: related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901884).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with Rails, then you can do

```
some_class_name.constantize
```

Example

```
"User".constantize
# => User
```

`remove_const` works, but you need to call it from the object space where the constant is defined. Also, remember to pass a symbol as the constant name.

Example

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :Foo)
```

Comment: Thanks! Regarding remove_const: the response was basically that ruby was expecting the `.rb` to define the constant that I had eliminated. In other words it worked, but didn't reset the system to before the class was loaded.

Comment: So how do you reset the system to before the constant was defined?